# How can I use the pattern matching result in the List of matching type?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, akka

I've found some weird behaviour in Akka. When I matching the pattern, I cannot add a message to the list:

```
  var msgs: List[Message] = Message() :: Nil

  ...

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case msg @ Message  => { 
      msgs = msgs.::(Message())   // ok
      //msgs = msgs.::(msg)       // doesn't work
      sender ! "Thanks!" 
    }
    case Request => { sender ! msgs.head }
    case _       =>
  }
```

Is this a bug in `Scala` or `Akka`?

To fix it I need to case the type

```
msgs = msgs.::(msg.asInstanceOf[Message])
```

which is not a convenient solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are making a subtle mistake in the matching happening in your case statement. You are matching there against the `Message` companion object, not the `Message` case class.

Another way of looking at it is that the `case x @ Y` syntax can be thought of as saying "match with any instance of type `Y`, and then run the equivalent of `val x: Y = <incoming value>.asInstanceOf[Y]`", but here the inferred type you are providing is a parameter-less type called `Message`, which the compiler takes to be `object Message`, not `case class Message()`.

So, to fix the line, write in the parameter list. For example, if the `Message` class is defined as:

```
case class Message()
```

this will be:

```
case msg @ Message() => ...
```

If instead we had, say:

```
case class Message(text: String, id: Int)
```

then the case statement becomes something like:

```
case msg @ Message(txt, is) => ...
```

or, if we don't care (or need to use) the `text` and `id` parameters:

```
case msg @ Message(_, _) => ...
```

For a slightly more technically correct description of what is happening here, the case statement is actually attempting a match with any "unapply" methods available in the companion object (also called "extractors"). By default, there will be both an `apply` and an `unapply` method provided for free in the companion object for any case class that match exactly the parameter list provided in the case class constructor. In the second version of the `Message` class above, the relevant `unapply` method will have a signature like:

```
def unapply(text: String, id: Int): Option[Message]
```

You can read more about extractors [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/extractor-objects.html) and [here](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/11/21/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-1-extractors.html).

Comment: Oh, sure. Sorry for that question.